# Curly bracket around iterated exponentials

Tags: brackets, superscripts, alignment

I believe this problem must already have a solution but I cannot find one on the Internet.

Consider the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
 \begin{equation*}
  a=\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  p^{p^{p^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^p}}}}}\right\}\text{$n$-many $p$'s}
 \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

How does one make the height of the curly bracket equal to the height of the iterated exponential without any manual calculations or adjustments?

I want the baseline of the `a` and baseline of the lowest `p` to align.  In this case, the baseline of the `\text{$n$-many $p$'s}` would not align with the other baselines, but this text should be in the middle of the curly bracket in the usual way.

I believe there must be a clean solution using simple LaTeX without sophisticated packages like TiKZ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can vertically center the big expression, so the `\rbrace` can cover it exactly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    a=p^{p^{\scriptstyle p^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\scriptstyle p}}}}}}
  \end{array}
  \right\rbrace
  \text{\scriptsize $n$-many $p$'s}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more powerful version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcoffins}

\NewCoffin{\repexpbasecoffin}
\NewCoffin{\repexptextcoffin}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\repexp}{mom}
 {
  \wong_repexp:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \wong_repexp:nnn
 {
  \tl_set:Nf \l__wong_repexp_exp_tl { \tl_tail:n { #1 } }
  \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #2 }
   {
    \tl_clear:N \l__wong_repexp_sub_tl
   }
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__wong_repexp_sub_tl { #2 }
   }
  \tl_set:Nx \l__wong_repexp_base_tl
   {
    $
    \tl_head:n { #1 }
    \tl_map_function:NN \l__wong_repexp_exp_tl \__wong_repexp_exp:n
    \prg_replicate:nn { \tl_count:N \l__wong_repexp_exp_tl } { \c_group_end_token }
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l__wong_repexp_sub_tl
     {
      \tl_map_function:NN \l__wong_repexp_sub_tl \__wong_repexp_sub:n
      \prg_replicate:nn { \tl_count:N \l__wong_repexp_exp_tl } { \c_group_end_token }
     }
    $
   }
  \SetHorizontalCoffin{\repexpbasecoffin}{\tl_use:N \l__wong_repexp_base_tl}
  \SetHorizontalCoffin{\repexptextcoffin}
   {
    $
    \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
    \vphantom{\begin{tabular}{c}\tl_use:N \l__wong_repexp_base_tl\end{tabular}}
    \right\rbrace
    \text{\scriptsize #3}
    $
   }
  \JoinCoffins\repexpbasecoffin[r,vc]\repexptextcoffin[l,vc]
  \TypesetCoffin\repexpbasecoffin
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__wong_repexp_exp:n
 {
  \c_math_superscript_token \c_group_begin_token \scriptstyle
  \str_if_eq:nnTF { . } { #1 } { \cdot } { \exp_not:n { #1 } }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__wong_repexp_sub:n
 {
  \c_math_subscript_token \c_group_begin_token \scriptstyle
  \str_if_eq:nnTF { . } { #1 } { \cdot } { \exp_not:n { #1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\repexp{ppp...p}{$n$ many $p$'s}
\\
a=\repexp{ppp...p}{$n$ many $p$'s}
\\
\mathfrak{q}=\repexp{{\aleph_0}{\aleph_0}{\aleph_0}...{\aleph_0}}{$q$}
\\
\repexp{abcd...x}[bcd...x]{$n$ up, $m$ down}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

As you see, the big exponential can be used on its own. The syntax is also simplified: simple letters can be inserted directly, complex symbols should be braced; a period stands for `\cdot`.

The optional argument is for subscripts, see the final example.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I accepted your answer because it solves the problem as I stated it. However, the solution is unsatisfactory because semantically it puts the curly bracket on the equation, not the term on the right-hand side of the equation. Should I consider this a different question and pose it separately?

Comment: @LawrenceWong I can't see the difference. Do you need such a beast more than once in your document? Wasting time for “semantic satisfaction” doesn't seem good. `;-)`

Comment: Unfortunately, I do need to use this many times in my document. In case you need a more specific reason, I am writing some notes about large countable ordinals, on which various processes iterate in the superscripts/subscripts. In particular, I will need to write equations involving these terms.

Comment: @egreg Wonderful your answers. I like very much for completeness, accuracy and setup. With sincerity my warmest regards. +1

Comment: @LawrenceWong I added to the “power version" also subscripts.

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much! The syntax looks simple and the output looks exactly what I want. I will need to contact the IT people at my department to get LaTeX3 to run here though. Does your answer imply that my initial belief that there is a simple solution in LaTeX (meaning LaTeX2e) is wrong?

Comment: @LawrenceWong One can do the same with legacy macros, but it would require heavy computations.