# Huge white space in fraction

Tags: equations, amsmath

I'm trying to create an equation in LaTeX, however, there seems to be a gigantic white space that is rather unsightly. Here's the code I'm using:

```
\[
x=a\sqrt[n]{1-\left(\dfrac{\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{\sqrt[2-n]{\left(\dfrac{a} 
{b}\right)^{2n}}}{\dfrac{1}{a^n}+\dfrac{1}{b^n}\left(\sqrt[2-n] 
{\left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^{2n}}\right)}}}{b}\right)^n}
\]
```

[image]

Is there a way to shorten the braces and root so that they look somewhat closer to this?
[image]

Comment: The short answer is that it is the parentheses that are the problem, not the fraction per se: For TeX likes to make parenteses symmetrical about the math axis, which in this case is the main fraction bar. (I think I saw an answer to a related question recently that dealt with this. I'll see if I can manage to find it again …)

Comment: Ah, found it. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/455248) deals with a somewhat similar problem. You might have a look and see if you can adapt it to your situation. (Or if not, perhaps someone else reading this can step in and help out.)

Comment: moving the parenthesis of the math axis makes rather ugly output, can you not use `\left(\frac{1}{b}\sqrt{.....}\right)`

Comment: Related: [How do I fix the vertical alignment of the bracketed part of this equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/295961/5764), [Is there a way to modify the default vertical spacing conventions of LaTeX left and right delimiters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25445/5764)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure such a horrible formula can help the reader.

Anyway it's possible to make it less ugly without guessing dimensions. I added a two-story version, anyhow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\sbox0{$\displaystyle
  \dfrac{
    \sqrt[n]{
      \dfrac{
        \sqrt[2-n]{\left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^{2n}}
      }{
        \dfrac{1}{a^n}+
        \dfrac{1}{b^n}\sqrt[2-n]{\left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^{2n}}
      }
    }
  }{b}
$}
%
x=a\sqrt[n]{
  1-
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\depth-3\fontdimen22\textfont2}{$
    \left(\begin{gathered}\usebox{0}\end{gathered}\:\right)^n
  $}
}
\]

\[
x=a
\left(1-
  \left(
    \dfrac{1}{b}
    \sqrt[n]{
      \dfrac{
        (a/b)^{2n/(2-n)}
      }{
        a^{-n}+b^{-n}(a/b)^{2n/(2-n)}
      }
    }\,
  \right)^{\!\!n}\;
\right)^{\!\!1/n}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I propose this hack, found with trial and error:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\raisebox{-4.25ex}{$ x=a $}\sqrt[n]{\raisebox{-4.25ex}{$ 1- {}$}\begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{\sqrt[2-n]{\left(\dfrac{a}
{b}\right)^{2n}}}{\dfrac{1}{a^n}+\dfrac{1}{b^n}\left(\sqrt[2-n]
{\left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^{2n}}\right)}}}{\begin{matrix}b \\ \mbox{}\end{matrix}}\end{pmatrix}^n}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]